# Getting "(900906) - No matching resource found in the API" for existing resource in WSO2 API manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Have upgraded wso2 api manager 2.6.0 to 3.2.0
and Identity Server 5.7.0 to 5.10.0, we have integrated wso2 identity server -5.10.0 as a key manager with APIM.
All the APIs which were published in APIM-2.6.0 are migrated to 3.2.0 and they are working fine. However I added new resource path to the existing API and saved it. If I tried to execute the new resource path getting below error response:

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900906</ams:code>
    <ams:message>No matching resource found in the API for the given request</ams:message>
    <ams:description>Access failure for API: /reports/v1.0.0, version: v1.0.0 status: (900906) - No matching resource found in the API for the given request. Check the API documentation and add a proper REST resource path to the invocation URL</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

**And below error in WSO2 logs:**

```
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} - API authentication failure due to No matching resource found in the API for the given request
```

**Observing this issue after changing admin password for IS and APIM, have followed below steps to change the password:**

**Changing admin password for IS-5.10.0:** https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/#changing-the-super-admin-password

**Changing admin password for APIM-3.2.0:** https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/security/logins-and-passwords/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/#change-the-super-admin-credentials

**Attaching the wireLogs for the API:/test1**

```
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,851] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "GET /reports/v1.0.0/test1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,852] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Host: 10.75.80.104:8280[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,852] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,852] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "AUTH_TOKEN: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1aWNoZWNrQHRhdGFlbHhzaS5jby5pbiIsIkZpcnN0TmFtZSI6InVpY2hlY2siLCJyb2xlcyI6IlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJ0b2tlbl9hY2Nlc3MiOiJhY2Nlc3MiLCJMYXN0TmFtZSI6InVpY2hlY2siLCJleHAiOjE2NjUwMzc4NzEsInVzZXJpZCI6MSwiZGV2aWNlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2MzM1MDE4NzEsImp0aSI6IjdmOTc2ZTg2LTdiMDgtNGIzZi05ZjA2LWYxNTBlNWRhYzdiZCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidWljaGVja0B0YXRhZWx4c2kuY28uaW4ifQ.wzlNwFnd2KsvnuFmhvTWkDCDwNgklIs4660iPu7R6Z0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,853] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Authorization: Bearer 5cee06c5-2195-3d3f-888f-38cf2356fa9f[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,853] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,854] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,854] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Postman-Token: a721233f-49b3-abcc-dd26-651602f59b63[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,854] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,855] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,855] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,855] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Cookie: JSESSIONID=4C0E34D44696583993A06B1B28613614[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,856] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,857]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} - API authentication failure due to No matching resource found in the API for the given request
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,858] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,858] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Cookie: JSESSIONID=4C0E34D44696583993A06B1B28613614[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,858] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "AUTH_TOKEN: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1aWNoZWNrQHRhdGFlbHhzaS5jby5pbiIsIkZpcnN0TmFtZSI6InVpY2hlY2siLCJyb2xlcyI6IlJPTEVfQURNSU4iLCJ0b2tlbl9hY2Nlc3MiOiJhY2Nlc3MiLCJMYXN0TmFtZSI6InVpY2hlY2siLCJleHAiOjE2NjUwMzc4NzEsInVzZXJpZCI6MSwiZGV2aWNlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2MzM1MDE4NzEsImp0aSI6IjdmOTc2ZTg2LTdiMDgtNGIzZi05ZjA2LWYxNTBlNWRhYzdiZCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidWljaGVja0B0YXRhZWx4c2kuY28uaW4ifQ.wzlNwFnd2KsvnuFmhvTWkDCDwNgklIs4660iPu7R6Z0[\r][\n
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,859] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,859] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,859] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,859] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,859] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,859] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Postman-Token: a721233f-49b3-abcc-dd26-651602f59b63[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,859] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,859] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,860] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction,apikey,testKey,CMS_TOKEN,AUTH_TOKEN,responseType,Authorization[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,860] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,860] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Date: Wed, 06 Oct 2021 06:51:16 GMT[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,860] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,860] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,860] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,860] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "1b9[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,860] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900906</ams:code><ams:message>No matching resource found in the API for the given request</ams:message><ams:description>Access failure for API: /reports/v1.0.0, version: v1.0.0 status: (900906) - No matching resource found in the API for the given request. Check the API documentation and add a proper REST resource path to the invocation URL</ams:description></ams:fault>[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,861] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-06 12:21:16,861] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"
```

**Attaching the errors got while adding new resourcePath and publishing the API:**

```
TID: [-1234] [AuthenticationAdmin] [2021-10-20 16:00:21,559]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} - 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2021-10-20 16:00:21,559+0530]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-10-20 16:00:22,164]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin connected
TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-20 16:00:22,196] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection} - Throwable Received but no listener set. org.wso2.andes.AMQDisconnectedException: Server closed connection and reconnection not permitted.
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.closed(AMQProtocolHandler.java:274)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.closeConnection(AMQProtocolHandler.java:755)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolSession.closeProtocolSession(AMQProtocolSession.java:379)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ConnectionCloseMethodHandler.methodReceived(ConnectionCloseMethodHandler.java:104)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.dispatchConnectionClose(ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.java:192)
        at org.wso2.andes.framing.amqp_0_91.ConnectionCloseBodyImpl.execute(ConnectionCloseBodyImpl.java:140)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.state.AMQStateManager.methodReceived(AMQStateManager.java:111)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.methodBodyReceived(AMQProtocolHandler.java:554)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolSession.methodFrameReceived(AMQProtocolSession.java:467)
        at org.wso2.andes.framing.AMQMethodBodyImpl.handle(AMQMethodBodyImpl.java:92)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler$2.run(AMQProtocolHandler.java:487)
        at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.processAll(Job.java:111)
        at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.run(Job.java:158)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

TID: [-1] [] [2021-10-20 16:00:22,196] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory} - Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : notificationJMSPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=notification} javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: not allowed
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:53)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:268)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory$PoolableJMSConnectionFactory.makeObject(JMSConnectionFactory.java:356)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromPool(JMSConnectionFactory.java:286)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: not allowed [error code 530: not allowed]
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:496)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.client.AMQAuthenticationException: not allowed [error code 530: not allowed]
        at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ConnectionCloseMethodHandler.methodReceived(ConnectionCloseMethodHandler.java:79)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.handler.ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.dispatchConnectionClose(ClientMethodDispatcherImpl.java:192)
        at org.wso2.andes.framing.amqp_0_91.ConnectionCloseBodyImpl.execute(ConnectionCloseBodyImpl.java:140)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.state.AMQStateManager.methodReceived(AMQStateManager.java:111)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler.methodBodyReceived(AMQProtocolHandler.java:554)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolSession.methodFrameReceived(AMQProtocolSession.java:467)
        at org.wso2.andes.framing.AMQMethodBodyImpl.handle(AMQMethodBodyImpl.java:92)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler$2.run(AMQProtocolHandler.java:487)
        at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.processAll(Job.java:111)
        at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.run(Job.java:158)
        ... 3 more
```

**Followed below link for encrypting password and connectionUrl using cipher tool:**

[17:58] Amulya M
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Encrypting+Passwords+with+Cipher+Tool

Encoded admin password and updated 'deployment.toml' file as shown below:
`[apim.throttling.jms]`
`username = "admin"`
`password = "encodedPassword"`

**Encoded 'connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory' URL in jndi2.properties**

connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:adminpwd@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://${carbon.local.ip}:${jms.port}'

**However getting below error after restarting APIM:**

**ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator} - Did not found valid API Validation Information cache configuration. Use default configurationjava.lang.NullPointerException**
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-11-15 17:31:52,650] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator} - Did not found valid API Resource Validation Information cache configuration. Use default configurationjava.lang.NullPointerException
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-11-15 17:31:52,666] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.GatewayUtils} - Did not found valid API Validation Information cache configuration. Use default configuration. java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.internal.ServiceReferenceHolder.getAPIManagerConfiguration_aroundBody12(ServiceReferenceHolder.java:100)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.internal.ServiceReferenceHolder.getAPIManagerConfiguration(ServiceReferenceHolder.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.GatewayUtils.isGatewayTokenCacheEnabled_aroundBody56(GatewayUtils.java:868)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.GatewayUtils.isGatewayTokenCacheEnabled(GatewayUtils.java:865)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.(JWTValidator.java:76)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.init_aroundBody0(OAuthAuthenticator.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.init(OAuthAuthenticator.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.initializeAuthenticators_aroundBody34(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:300)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.initializeAuthenticators(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:239)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody36(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:352)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:325)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:373)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:73)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:99)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:426)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Did you republish the API after adding the new resource? Can you invoke other resources and other APIs without any issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving the changes please make sure that the relevant gateway has been selected under the publisher's Environment UI. Also, please redeploy the API via the Lifecycle UI. Then try to check the flow again.

Comment: Hi @Saranki Magenthirarajah, thankyou for your response, gateway is added and other resource paths executing fine, have redeployed the API .still facing same issue

Comment: Can you please share the curl command to generate the access token and invoke the API call for which you are getting no matching resource error? In the APIM devportal can you try to invoke the same API resource with the test key and share the response?

Comment: Hi @Saranki Magenthirarajah
We are using  https://localhost:8243/token to generate access_token with the scopes associated with the  API, Above Issue is resolved after restarting APIM but same Error is coming again for the newly added resource path

Comment: So after you publish the API to the devportal, were you able to view the added resource path in the devportal? Can you enable the wire logs and invoke the API call again?

Comment: Hi 
Saranki Magenthirarajah, After publishing the API it is available in devportal. Attached the wirelogs for the sample request

Comment: Hi @AmulyaM, in the wire logs I can observe the following exception and error. This indicates that the user who tries to invoke the GET /reports/v1.0.0/test1 resource doesn't have enough permissions. Please check the scopes of the user if there are any scopes attached to this method and check the user permissions as well.


 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} - API authentication failure due to No matching resource found in the API for the given request


HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"

Comment: Hi @Saranki Magenthirarajah
User have access to the scope and able to execute the other API assigned with same scope, for newly added resource path we are getting this error even if it doesn't have the scope.

Comment: @AmulyaM, are you having a distributed setup? or an All-in-one? After adding a new resource, if you restart the API Manager server (just to check), were you able to invoke the API with success?

Comment: @Athiththan
We are having All-in-one setup, After adding a new resource, if we restart the API Manager server We are getting success response for the API

Comment: Do you see any errors while publishing an API from the Publisher portal? Any WARN or ERROR traces observed in carbon logs related to AMQP connections or any?

Comment: Yes @Athiththan, Attaching the errors got while adding new resourcePath and publishing the API

Comment: It seems the Connection URL Strings in `jndi.properties` are either wrong or mismatching. Have you encrypted the credentials using the ciphertool in your environment? including the passwords in the `jndi.properties`? Check, whether the connection strings and the credentials are matching in the `jndi.properties` according to your environment.

Comment: Hi @Athiththan, connection url is proper and Password is encrypted in `jndi.properties` , Attaching  `jndi.properties` above

Comment: If you are using Ciphertool to encrypt the credentials, then it is required to encrypt the complete `connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory` property, and only encrypting the password and appending it to the connection factory URL may cause the above behaviour. Therefore, can you try ciphering the complete Topic Connection URL?

Comment: Hi @Athiththan , should we replace '${carbon.local.ip}:${jms.port}' with values in 'connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory' URL before encoding

Comment: @Athiththan Have encoded connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory , getting error while running APIM , have attached the logs above

Comment: face the same issue